# How to Change Form Action when Form Submit Using Jquery Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, action, persist

i am trying to perform update and delete operation on row. i am using Jquery Ajax function for it . i have written two Jquery function separately to perform an operation. both functions have different action(URL), but when i am trying to call deleteRow() after performing updateRow() or vice-versa, the action(URL) value is persist for first function call. here is my code --

```
function updateRow() {
$("#my_form").submit(function(e)
{
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/update?",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("SUCCESS");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    e.unbind();
});
$("#my_form").submit();
}


function deleteRow() {
$("#my_form").submit(function(e)
{
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/delete?",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("SUCCESS");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    e.unbind();
});
$("#my_form").submit();
}
```

Comment: The logic of your functions seems odd. You're adding handlers under a function call then immediately calling those functions. Under what event is `updateRow` and `deleteRow` called?

Answer (score 0):

You should not bind submit if you are calling different function for update and delete rows try it like,

```
function updateRow() {
    var postData = $('#my_form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/update?",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            deleteRow(); // call delete after update function callback
            alert("SUCCESS");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });       
    return false;// use return false, to prevent page load
}

function deleteRow() {
    var postData = $('#my_form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/delete?",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("SUCCESS");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Assuming that you are using 2 elements to call the above 2 function.